# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/yup.js?v=3827e2ab' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: reactjs, vite, formik, yup

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkZ30.png)

I encountered an issue while working with Formik in a Vite project. Specifically, when I attempted to implement form validation using Yup with Formik, I encountered an error. To address this, I found that importing Yup using the following syntax resolved the issue:

`import * as yup from 'yup';`

This allowed me to successfully integrate Yup for form validation within the Formik framework in my Vite project.